# Why does Navigation Drawer "Flicker" with GoogleMap & Googlemap Extensions main content

Tags: android, android-navigation

I have an android application that has a GoogleMap as its main content.
The application employs a Navigation Drawer `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`

I have followed the android developers example "Creating a Navigation Drawer".
When the navigation drawer opens, initially everything looks as expected, then after a few seconds the shadow over the visible main content starts to "Flicker" e.g. disappears and re appears
why does it behave this way?
has anyone experienced the same behavior?
**UPDATE**
i have investigated this more and believe there is a compatibility issue between
the navigation drawer and google map extentions fragment
`pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.SupportMapFragment`
i started with the navigation drawer example supplied by google (the one that allows you to select different images of planets in our solar system)
i then simply replaced the Fragment for displaying the image of a planet for this...

 `fragment android:id="@+id/map"

 android:name="pl.mg6.android.maps.extensions.SupportMapFragment"

 android:layout_width="match_parent"

 android:layout_height="match_parent"`



now when i open the navigation drawer the visible part of the map initially gets shaded
darker (as it should do when the navigation drawer opens) 
but within a few seconds the shadow disappears and starts flickering.
what do i have to do to get the shadow to stay constant and not keep disppearing?
**UPDATE 2**
The exact same "flickering" occurs with

`fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:id="@+id/map"

        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Comment: yes, add a transparent "layer" over the map, works a treat

Comment: @Hector You saved my day! You should definitely post your answer!